# Как отключить всплытие событий в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
return(

    <div className='portfolio-panel' id='porfolioPanel' ref={this.props.link}>
        <div className='portfolio-panel-background' ref={this.props.linkCircle} onTransitionEnd={this.showWorks} >
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName='portfolio-panel__information'
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {middleElementCircle}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            <div style={diskStyle} className='portfolio-panel-disk' id='portfolio-panel-disk'>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName='work-item'
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {workItems}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

В данном примере кода отлавливается событие `onTransitionEnd={this.showWorks}`, когда заканчивается анимация, нужно отобразить элемент внутри `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` сам работает через transition и судя по всему срабатывает та же самая функция `onTransitionEnd={this.showWorks}` и элемент пропадает. В итоге анимация работает в одну и в другую сторону сразу. Я думаю это из-за всплытия события, как его можно отключить в `React`?

Попробовал сделать так:

```
this.showWorks = (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.setState({
                showWorks: !this.state.showWorks,
            })
        }

onTransitionEnd={(e) => {this.showWorks(e); console.log(1)}}
```

P.S. `console.log(1);` выбивает 10 раз единицу в консоль

Весь компонент:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

import WorkItem from '../WorkItem';

class PortfolioSectionPanel extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showWorks: false,
            wheelAngleinDeg: 0,
            counterActiveType: 0,
            works: [
                {
                    type: 'Веб-разработка',
                    link: 'some',
                    text: 'Закажите веб-разработку'
                },
                {
                    type: 'Копирайтинг',
                    link: 'some',
                    text: 'Закажите копирайтинг'

                },
                {
                    type: 'Продвижение',
                    link: 'some1',
                    text: 'Закажите продвижение'
                },
                {
                    type: 'Скриптинг',
                    link: 'some',
                    text: 'Закажите скриптинг'
                },
                {
                    type: 'Веб-дизайн',
                    link: 'some1',
                    text: 'Закажите веб-дизайн'
                },
                
            ],
        }

        this.showWorks = (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.setState({
                showWorks: !this.state.showWorks,
            })
        }

        this.countActiveType = (direction) => {
            if(direction == 'left') {
                if(this.state.counterActiveType == this.state.works.length - 1) {
                    this.setState({
                        counterActiveType: 0,
                    })
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        counterActiveType: this.state.counterActiveType + 1,
                    })
                }

                
                
            } else {
                if(this.state.counterActiveType == 0) {
                    this.setState({
                        counterActiveType: this.state.works.length - 1,
                    })
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        counterActiveType: this.state.counterActiveType - 1,
                    })
                }
                
            }

            console.log(this.state.counterActiveType)
        }

        this.angleInDeg = 360 / this.state.works.length;
        

    }
    
    render() {


        //Расположение кругов
        let workItems;

        if(this.state.showWorks) {
            let {works} = this.state;

            const angleRad = 360 / works.length * 0.017; //Частота кругов в радианах
            const bg = document.getElementById('portfolio-panel-disk');
            let radius;
            if(bg) {
                radius = parseInt(getComputedStyle(bg).width) / 2;
            }

            workItems = works.map((currentValue, index) => {
                return <WorkItem 
                        type={currentValue.type} 
                        link={currentValue.link} 
                        key={index + 50} 
                        leftOffset={radius - radius * Math.cos(angleRad * index)}
                        topOffset={radius - radius * Math.sin(angleRad * index)}
                        angle={-this.state.wheelAngleinDeg}  />
            })
        } else {
            workItems = null;
        }

        let diskStyle = {
            transform: `translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(${this.state.wheelAngleinDeg}deg)`,
        };

        //Элементы внутри круга

        let middleElementCircle;
        
        if(this.state.showWorks) {
            middleElementCircle = <div className='portfolio-panel__information'>
                <h3 className='portfolio-panel__title'>
                    <a href='#'>
                        {this.state.works[this.state.counterActiveType].type}
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <p className='portfolio-panel__description'>
                    {this.state.works[this.state.counterActiveType].text}
                </p>
                <div className='portfolio-panel__navigation'>
                    <svg onClick={() => {this.setState({wheelAngleinDeg: this.state.wheelAngleinDeg - this.angleInDeg}); this.countActiveType('left')}} className='portfolio-panel__arrow portfolio-panel__arrow--perv'>
                        <use xlinkHref='img/icons/sprite.svg#arrow-left' />
                    </svg>
                    <div className='portfolio-panel__share'>/</div>
                    <svg onClick={() => {this.setState({wheelAngleinDeg: this.state.wheelAngleinDeg + this.angleInDeg}); this.countActiveType('right')}} className='portfolio-panel__arrow portfolio-panel__arrow--perv'>
                        <use xlinkHref='img/icons/sprite.svg#arrow-right' />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div> 
        } else {
            middleElementCircle = null
        }
                                    
         

        return(

            <div className='portfolio-panel' id='porfolioPanel' ref={this.props.link}>
                <div className='portfolio-panel-background' ref={this.props.linkCircle} onTransitionEnd={(e) => {this.showWorks(e); console.log(1)}} >
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                        transitionName='portfolio-panel__information'
                        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                            {middleElementCircle}
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    <div style={diskStyle} className='portfolio-panel-disk' id='portfolio-panel-disk'>
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                        transitionName='work-item'
                        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                            {workItems}
                        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
    

export default PortfolioSectionPanel;
```

Comment: e.stopPropagation()?

Comment: Это засовывать в функцию, которая находится в transitionend?

Comment: У вас классовый компонент? В попробуйте создать метод что-нибудь типа `handleClose: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }` И в `transitionEnd` запустить её

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, Посмотрите, я отредактировал ответ, Вы так имели ввиду? Если да, то не помогает

Comment: А можно весь компонент?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, Прикрепил весь компонент

Comment: Может в `this.showsWork` поставить какой-нибудь флаг, который спустя первое изменение изменился бы на `true` и не пропускал последующие изменения?